# How to fix Pylint's false positive Unable to import error?

Tags: python, module, python-import, pylint

For last couple of hours I was trying to figure out what's the Pythonic way of importing modules from parent directory and from sub-directories. I made a project just for testing purposes and hosted it on [github](https://github.com/blablaalb/python-test), so you could take a look at it to better understand my question.
In the project we have the following files structure:

```
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── project
    ├── a.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── subdirectory
        ├── b.py
        └── __init__.py
```

I'm trying to figure out how to import modules from subdirectories and from the parent directories. 
If I try to import the modules `./project/subdirectories/b.py`and `./project/a.py` into the `main.py` module without specifying the root directory's name in the import statement then **pylint** starts to complain that it's unable to locate the modules, but the program runs fine:[image]
If I do specify the root directory in the import statement then the **pylint** stops complaining, but the program doesn't run anymore:[image]
Can someone, please, explain to me why do I have those false positive from **pylint** when the program does work and if I make the **pylint** happy, by specifying the root directory in the import statement, then the program stops working?

Comment: sounds like a bug in Pylint to me. You can open a bug on GitHub and meanwhile disable this message with pylint writing this at the top line of your module :
# pylint: disable=import-error

Comment: I asked the same question on `reddit.com/r/learnpython` and was told to remove the `__init__.py` file from the root directory. I removed it and the *pylint* started working properly. I'll probably leave the question open until someone leaves comprehensive answer on why the `__init__.py` is redundant in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE (and thus pylint) expect the code to be launched from the root of your git repository not from the directory above it. There is no `test` directory in your git project structure. So I think the import `from test.project import a` is working only because your git repository itself is named `test` and because you launch the program from above the project directory.
Ie your real structure is this:

```
    test
    ├── .git # root of git repository inside test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py
    └── project
        ├── a.py
        ├── __init__.py
        └── subdirectory
            ├── b.py
            └── __init__.py
```

But the test directory is not inside git and for the IDE the git root as the source root. If you start launching `__main__` from the same directory you're launching pylint from, then pylint indication will be accurate. So the fix is to create the test directory inside your git project:

```
    .git # root of git repository outside test/
    test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py
    └── project
        ├── a.py
        ├── __init__.py
        └── subdirectory
            ├── b.py
            └── __init__.py
```

You could also launch pylint from the same directory you launch the code by changing the root directory of your IDE.

Comment: I just followed your answer and created another [test directory alongside the `.git`](https://i.imgur.com/CxVHJme.png). [Nothing changed](https://i.imgur.com/wHRLgUm.png)